# Checking Sudoku - sufficient sums

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Are the following condition sufficient for checking if solution of Sudoku with (***extended output***) is valide :

- sum of values in each row, column and subsquare is equal to 45 and
- sum of squares of values in each row, column and subsquare is equal to 285

By ***extended output*** I mean that the error could be made, such that each value could be from range <-1000,1000> for example. As you see it is some kind of generalization of possible output of sudoku, but rules of Sudoku are **unchanged**.

If you need additional information or want to know my motivation please ask.

Comment: ok I have not answer but information that make my question invalide http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157682/does-a-solved-sudoku-game-always-have-same-sum-is-this-sum-unique-to-solved-gam?rq=1 my condition could be substituted by taking sums of 2^value, but I'm not sure on 100%

Comment: Yes, as shown in the question you link to, if you check all rows, columns, and subsquares with the $2^{k-1}$ weighting and get $511$ each time, you have a valid Sudoku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you are asking whether there exists any set of 9 integers

$a\le b\le c\le d\le e\le f\le g\le h\le j$

such that

$a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+j = 45$

and simultaneously

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2+g^2+h^2+j^2 = 285$

other than the trivial solution $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.

In Mathematica, that's

```
FindInstance[
    a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + g^2 + h^2 + j^2 = 285
        && a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + j = 45,
    {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j},
    Integers
]
```

but I don't have access to Mathematica so I don't know what it'd come up with.

A trivial computer program can find all the answers easily, though, because of that second equation. We know that all the $x^2$s are positive quantities, so none of the $x$s can possibly be outside the range $[-16,16]$.

```
int main()
{
 for (int a=-16; a <= 16; ++a) {
  for (int b=a; b <= 16; ++b) {
   for (int c=b; c <= 16; ++c) {
    for (int d=c; d <= 16; ++d) {
     for (int e=d; e <= 16; ++e) {
      for (int f=e; f <= 16; ++f) {
       for (int g=f; g <= 16; ++g) {
        for (int h=g; h <= 16; ++h) {
         for (int j=h; j <= 16; ++j) {
          if (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+j != 45) continue;
          if (a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d + e*e + f*f + g*g + h*h + j*j != 285) continue;
          printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j);
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This program takes six-tenths of a second to run on my MacBook Pro, and finds 80 distinct solutions:

```
-2 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 7
-2 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7
-1 2 5 6 6 6 7 7 7
-1 2 6 6 6 6 6 6 8
-1 3 4 5 6 6 7 7 8
-1 3 5 5 5 6 6 8 8
-1 3 5 5 6 6 6 6 9
-1 4 4 4 5 7 7 7 8
-1 4 4 4 6 6 6 8 8
-1 4 4 5 5 5 7 8 8
-1 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 9
0 1 4 6 6 7 7 7 7
0 1 5 5 6 6 7 7 8
0 2 3 5 6 7 7 7 8
0 2 3 6 6 6 6 8 8
0 2 4 4 6 6 7 8 8
0 2 4 5 5 6 7 7 9
0 2 5 5 5 5 6 8 9
0 3 3 4 5 7 7 8 8
0 3 3 4 6 6 7 7 9
0 3 3 5 5 5 8 8 8
0 3 3 5 5 6 6 8 9
0 3 4 4 4 6 8 8 8
0 3 4 4 4 7 7 7 9
0 3 4 4 5 5 7 8 9
0 3 4 4 6 6 6 6 10
0 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 10
0 4 4 4 4 6 6 7 10
0 4 4 4 5 5 5 9 9
1 1 3 5 6 6 7 8 8
1 1 3 6 6 6 6 7 9
1 1 4 4 5 7 7 8 8
1 1 4 4 6 6 7 7 9
1 1 4 5 5 5 8 8 8
1 1 4 5 5 6 6 8 9
1 1 5 5 5 6 6 6 10
1 2 2 4 7 7 7 7 8
1 2 2 5 5 7 7 8 8
1 2 2 5 6 6 7 7 9
1 2 3 3 6 7 7 8 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 5 5 6 6 7 10
1 2 4 4 5 5 6 9 9
1 2 4 4 5 5 7 7 10
1 2 4 5 5 5 5 8 10
1 3 3 3 4 7 8 8 8
1 3 3 3 6 6 6 7 10
1 3 3 4 4 5 8 8 9
1 3 3 4 4 6 6 9 9
1 3 3 4 4 6 7 7 10
1 3 3 4 5 5 6 8 10
1 3 4 4 4 4 7 9 9
1 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 11
1 4 4 4 4 5 5 7 11
2 2 2 3 6 6 8 8 8
2 2 2 3 6 7 7 7 9
2 2 2 4 4 7 8 8 8
2 2 2 4 6 6 6 7 10
2 2 2 5 5 5 6 9 9
2 2 2 5 5 5 7 7 10
2 2 3 3 4 7 7 8 9
2 2 3 3 5 5 8 8 9
2 2 3 3 5 6 6 9 9
2 2 3 3 5 6 7 7 10
2 2 3 4 4 5 7 9 9
2 2 3 4 4 6 6 8 10
2 2 3 5 5 5 6 6 11
2 2 4 4 4 4 7 8 10
2 2 4 4 4 6 6 6 11
2 2 4 4 5 5 5 7 11
2 3 3 3 3 6 8 8 9
2 3 3 3 4 5 7 8 10
2 3 3 3 5 6 6 6 11
2 3 3 4 4 5 5 9 10
2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7 11
2 4 4 4 4 4 4 8 11
3 3 3 3 4 4 6 9 10
3 3 3 4 4 4 5 8 11
3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 12
3 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 12
```

Answer (score 1):

By extended output you mean integers right?

Otherwise the equations $x+y+z =45$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=285$ have real solution see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/i=solve+x+y+z=45+and+x%5E2+y%5E2+z%5E2=285).

Comment: yes integers   hjk,hj